# Visual Studio Code - image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform error

Tags: visual-studio, azure, docker

I have been following the tutorial posted here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-function

I tried the **Build and Push IoT Edge Solution** listed in step #6 of the **Build your IoT Edge solution** step and got the following error:

**Step 1/3 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-functions-binding:1.0.0-linux-amd64
1.0.0-linux-amd64: Pulling from azureiotedge-functions-binding
image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform**

So I noticed in the CSharpFunction module folder several Dockerfile objects. 1 is Windows and the other 3 are linux, including the one that caused the error. Since all the docker files and the command to do the build and push are app-generated, what settings or other options are available to force it to use the correct Docker container for the build and/or deployment? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the setting I was looking for is located in the deployment.template.json file itself. In the project folder, VS Code created four docker files:

**Dockerfile.amd64**

**Dockerfile.amd64.debug**

**Dockerfile.arm32v7**

**Dockerfile.windows-amd64**

In the CSharpFunction dictionary there is an image key which must refer to the container. The default setting was:

```
"${MODULES.CSharpFunction.amd64}"
```

Changing it to:

```
"${MODULES.CSharpFunction.windows-amd64}"
```

Fixes the problem.

Comment: Good find.  Another thing to be careful about in this tutorial is step #3.  You can name the modulename in any format you want like camel notation.  However, when you enter the image repository name you have to enter first the {registry server name}/modulename.  The modulename must be in lower case.